# How to get the html source of a page_object element?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, page-object-gem

Imagine i have a div like (in Watir language):

```
@browser.div(:id, 'home_slideshow')
```

I need the html code inside to do some "magic regex" :). The way to get the div html code could be:

```
the_div_html = @browser.div(:id, 'home_slideshow').html
```

Ok. I'm using page_object gem and lets suppose i have the div as element, like:

```
div(:slide_show, :id => 'home_slideshow')
```

To get the html inside i can use:

```
the_div_html = slide_show_element.html
```

...but i get the DEPRECATION WARNING:

```
*** DEPRECATION WARNING
*** You are calling a method named attribute_value at home_page.rb:80:in `get_slide_code'.
*** This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.
*** This feature will be removed in the near future.
```

How can i get the html code using the page_object element? As some similar questions i made before, sure the answer is so easy, but i look into the Cheezy book, the whole stackoverflow and the page-object rubydoc info and i didn't found it. Can you please tell me the way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`slide_show_element.html` should return element HTML. Does it?

Deprecation warning just means page-object api does not support `#html` method yet. You should request it here: https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues?state=open

Comment: Hi! Yes, it returns the HTML correctly. Only shows the Deprecation warning at top as "warning". As writing the code right now, i don't want to use a deprecated function that maybe tomorrow will crash the test. I though there were a page-object method to get the element HTML source code. I'll request the method on the page-object issues page. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

As a temporary workaround, you could access the watir-webdriver element directly using `.element`.

The following would give you the html without the depreciation warning:

```
slide_show_element.element.html
```

Comment: It works (as all your answers...). As temporary workaround its fine. I also opened an [issue](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/146) to create the method if its interesting to do so. 

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I'll be adding this method to the gem in the next release.